# How can I get all elements name on html (My bad code run loop)

Tags: go

I want to get a document tree.
Then, first, I displayed all elements name.
But my code run loop.
How can I do?

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

func getTagName(s *goquery.Selection) {
    for _, n := range s.Nodes {
        if n.Type != html.ElementNode {
            continue
        }
        println(n.Data)
        getTagName(s.Children())
    }
}

func main() {
    doc, _ := goquery.NewDocument("https://news.ycombinator.com/")
    doc.Find("html body").Each(func(_ int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        getTagName(s)
    })
}
```

Comment: Weird, goquery says the img tag with src="y18.gif" has 59 children (when it should have none, img tags are self-closing)

Comment: I can reproduce with this minimal code : https://play.golang.org/p/u60bW3M8rm (it won't run on the playground, I just needed a place to share the code snippet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work with this:

```
package main

import (
    "os"

    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "golang.org/x/net/html"
)

var areWeLooping = make(map[*goquery.Selection]struct{})

func getTagName(s *goquery.Selection) {
    if _, weAreLooping := areWeLooping[s]; weAreLooping {
        println("loop detected")
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    areWeLooping[s] = struct{}{}

    for _, n := range s.Nodes {
        if n.Type != html.ElementNode {
            continue
        }
        println(n.Data)
    }

    s.Children().Each(func(_ int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        getTagName(s)
    })
}

func main() {
    doc, _ := goquery.NewDocument("https://news.ycombinator.com/")
    doc.Find("html body").Children().Each(func(_ int, s *goquery.Selection) {
        getTagName(s)
    })
}
```

Having `getTagName(s.Children())` inside the loop was causing trouble.

Comment: Wow! Excelent! You are genius.
I see. `Children()` not return child node.
It returns the nodes including children, that is the same hierarchy as that's receiver, isn't it?
Therefore I need `Each()`, aha!
Thank you for your kindness. Thank you very very much for helping me.